# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException "

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

I'm creating a music app using WinUI in C# where you have the ability to add a folder.
The "MediaPlaybackList_CurrentItemChanged" event calls the function to update the medatata.
However in the function I continue to get "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: ''" as an error after trying many solutions.

Here is the related code:

```
async private void MediaPlaybackList_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, CurrentMediaPlaybackItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    mediaPlaybackItem = e.NewItem;

    await setmetadata();
}

async private Task setmetadata()
{
    if (mediaPlaybackItem.Source.CustomProperties.TryGetValue("FilePath", out var filePathObj) && filePathObj is string filePath)
    {
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
        if (file != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Grabbed: " + filePath.ToString());
            MusicProperties fileAttrib = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();

            album = fileAttrib.Album;
            trackNumber = fileAttrib.TrackNumber.ToString();
            title = fileAttrib.Title;

            attribTitle.Text = "#" + trackNumber + " - " + title;
            attribAlbum.Text = album;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I've tried moving the function into a "task" (which is displayed in the code block) and have tried many different ways of getting the file's path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are accessing the UI from a thread that is not the **Main Thread**. In that case, you need to use the `DispatcherQueue`.

For example:

```cs
DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
{
    ttribTitle.Text = "#" + trackNumber + " - " + title;
});
```

I have this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtE_1v7X8Cc) that should help you understand about the `DispatcherQueue`.